# href multilink images

Tags: jquery, href

I'm not sure if its the best way of doing this, but I have a few images on my page, and want each of them to have a different action. The one below adds a record to a database when clicked, if I want to add another image to click to delete, how do I make it unique so my `.click` function can launch a delete.php file? (data is hard coded at the moment as you can see)

```
<a href=""><img src="/wp-content/themes/Atlantis/images/add.gif" /></a>

<script type="text/javascript">                                         
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("a").click(function() {

      $.ajax({                                      
        url: 'add.php',                           
        data: "Masterselect=11&UserID=55&Status=W",       
        dataType: 'json',                
      });

      alert("Thanks for adding");  
   });
});         

</script>
```

Comment: Check the button with `{ }` on it. It lets you format code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would name your links -- give them a class or id attribute

```
<a class="add" href=""><img src="/wp-content/themes/Atlantis/images/add.gif" /></a>
<a class="delete" href=""><img src="/wp-content/themes/Atlantis/images/delete.gif" /></a>
```

And then you could specify one function for the add button, another for the delete, and so on:

```
$("a.add").click(...);
$("a.delete").click(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put something unique there so you can do it, perhaps by adding a class to your link `delete`.

Then just `$('.delete')` and the rest should be obvious.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a class name for image give it as click event instead of ahref

give click event for image class

```
<img class="test1" src="add.gif" alt="Angry face" />

<img class="test2" src="delete.gif" alt="Angry face" />
```

add click events here

```
(document).ready(function() {
        $("test1").click(function() {

 }

    $("test2").click(function() {

     }
```

}